# How to uses Smack API UserSearchManager with local server?

Tags: xmpp, smack, openfire

This may look a very basic question but I am having a problem accessing OpenFire search function using this code:

```
    try {

        UserSearchManager search = new UserSearchManager(connection.getConnection());
        Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("search." + server);
        ...

    } catch (Exception e) {...}
```

The server here is a String with value something like "192.168.242.132", the code gets error from this line: `Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("search." + server);`

Essentially, the server is up and running as I can create account and login/logout.

I assume that the problem is with the "server" String value. Any one have encountered this kind of problem before?

EDIT: I have already added in /etc/hosts to resolve the IP address to myelastix-local.com and still having the same problem, it can access create / login api but search still does not work. Do I have to modify openfire server settings too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("search." + connection.getServiceName());
```

connection is the XMPPConnection.

Comment: Referring to the part: `"search." + connection.getServiceName()`, where can I find or configure the relevant string for my ejabberd setup?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you can call `getSearchForm()` with an IP? Try to provide the component ID, which is normally something like `"search.jabberserver.tld"`

Comment: Adding an entry in the hosts file won't help here. There is no reverse DNS lookup involved. Take a look at the source: The String from `getSearchFrom()` is written directly into the stanza. *Just set the String to "myelastix-local.com".*

Comment: thanks for the info, however I have already solved the issue hours ago.

Comment: @xybrek Then share the solution with us pls :)

Comment: sure please see my answer post.