# Search for existing user using xmpp/UserSearchManager in Android

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I have gone through [this1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149928/how-to-uses-smack-api-usersearchmanager-with-local-server), [this2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910219/problem-using-usersearch-in-xmpp-with-asmack) and [this3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931100/smack-api-user-search) but still cannot find the solution of the problem.

I could know where my problem is what I am doing in this code is:

1. Take the input from textbox and
2. Pass that value to check if the username supplied in the textbox exists or not
3. Whenever I click check button only "Function called" is displayed and is not performing search.

Here is my code what I done so far.

```
public class Registration extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private final static String SERVER_HOST = "10.0.2.2";
    private final static int SERVER_PORT = 5222;
    private static final String TAG = null;
    private ProviderManager pm;
    private EditText username;
    private Button btn;

    private XMPPConnection connection;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration);

        try {

            initConnection();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        username = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtregusername);

        btn=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btncheck);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);      
}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.btncheck:
            try {
                check();
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        break;

        }

    }

    private void check() throws XMPPException{ 
         Toast.makeText(this,"Function called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider());
        UserSearchManager search = new UserSearchManager(connection);  

        Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("search."+connection.getServiceName());  
        Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();  
        answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);  
        Toast.makeText(this,username.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        answerForm.setAnswer("search", username.getText().toString());  
        ReportedData data = search.getSearchResults(answerForm,"search."+connection.getServiceName());  

    if(data.getRows() != null)
        {
             Toast.makeText(this,"Username Exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
             Toast.makeText(this,"Username Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }


    private void initConnection() throws XMPPException{
     ConnectionConfiguration config=new ConnectionConfiguration(SERVER_HOST,SERVER_PORT);
      config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
      config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
      connection=new XMPPConnection(config);

      try {    

       connection.connect();
       }

    catch (XMPPException e) {     
          Log.e(TAG, "Error connection to XMPP Server");     
          e.printStackTrace(); 
          } 


    }   

}
```

Comment: What is ... the problem?! :) Can you post the exception log, or describe the problem?

Comment: As i have also mention in 3 no point, the problem is search is not performed I dont know where the problem is. I am trying this since 5 hours to find the bug.

Comment: why don't you just rely that the createUser (whatever is called) functoin, will throw an exception, if user already exists, than you catch the exception. Why would you need to explicitly check if user already exists?

Comment: @hovanessyan: I appreciate your suggestion..but i am sorry if i am wrong i have tried this try{                              AccountManager manager = conn.getAccountManager();
manager.createAccount(usename,password);} catch(...) but could get any result so..can u show the details of this please

Comment: Have you checked if you establish connection to server at all? Can you query the server for something and get a result back? Maybe can you possibly try to login and disconnect to the server with existing user, and monitor the logs of xmpp (is it Openfire) to see if the communication works?

Comment: Yah I have checked the connection...where can i go an write a query? i could not understand u?

Comment: do you have access to the server logs? what does it happen on the server side when you execute check()?

Comment: @hovanessyan: org.jivesoftware.openfire.IQRouter - User tried to authenticate with this server using an unknown receipient: <iq id="z9EoI-0" to="search.ramesh-pc" type="get" from="xyz-pc/13b2ba83"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:search"/></iq> ..this is the information of the log..

Comment: ok is 10.0.2.2 == search.ramesh-pc. What is the hostname (fqdm) of your server? This looks more like a setup problem, rather than wrong programming code.

Comment: I am not sure how the search works in xmpp, but when you're connecting, you're not supplying a username to your connection. Than you use this connection to create UserSearchManager. Check documentation if you need any specific permissions to initiate a search (e.g. user to be registered in XmppDomain).

Comment: before user register user have to check if the username is used or not so how can user register before doing that..10.0.2.2 is the local server and search.ramesh-pc is the search domain...

Comment: your code is "client code", so if the API is decent enough, it will throw you an error, that a user with this username, already exists (e.g. some of those error codes http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/XMPPError.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It solves my problem.

```
UserSearchManager search = new UserSearchManager(mXMPPConnection);  

Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("search."+mXMPPConnection.getServiceName());

Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();  
answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);  

answerForm.setAnswer("search", user);  

org.jivesoftware.smackx.ReportedData data = search.getSearchResults(answerForm,"search."+mXMPPConnection.getServiceName());  

if(data.getRows() != null)
{
    Iterator<Row> it = data.getRows();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Row row = it.next();
        Iterator iterator = row.getValues("jid");
        if(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            String value = iterator.next().toString();
            Log.i("Iteartor values......"," "+value);
        }
        //Log.i("Iteartor values......"," "+value);
    }
    Toast.makeText(_service,"Username Exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    );
}
```

If Server has not any entery with that specified name then Itearator it has no value and code will not go inside while(it.hasNext).

Comment: I get IllegalArgumentException at Form.set Answer("Username",true); any reason for this ? is it that some permission is missing on server ?

Comment: getting nullpointer at Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("search."+mXMPPConnection.getServiceName());

Comment: @SagarNayak might be your mXMPPConnection is null.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you need to use **ProviderManager** first, otherwise search will not work properly.Below is my working code which works perfectly, Hope it will help:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PrivacyList;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PrivacyListManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.PrivacyItem;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.PrivacyProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ProviderManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.Form;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.GroupChatInvitation;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.PrivateDataManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.ReportedData.Row;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.socks5.provider.BytestreamsProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.ChatStateExtension;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.LastActivity;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.OfflineMessageInfo;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.OfflineMessageRequest;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.SharedGroupsInfo;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.VCard;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.AdHocCommandDataProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.DataFormProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.DelayInformationProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.DiscoverInfoProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.DiscoverItemsProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.MUCAdminProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.MUCOwnerProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.MUCUserProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.MessageEventProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.MultipleAddressesProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.RosterExchangeProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.StreamInitiationProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.VCardProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.provider.XHTMLExtensionProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.search.UserSearch;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.search.UserSearchManager;
    public static List<String> getUserListBySearch(XMPPConnection mXMPPConnection, String searchString){
            ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider());
            List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                UserSearchManager search = new UserSearchManager(mXMPPConnection);  

                Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("search."+mXMPPConnection.getServiceName());
                Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();  
                answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);  
                answerForm.setAnswer("search", searchString);  
                org.jivesoftware.smackx.ReportedData data = search.getSearchResults(answerForm,"search."+mXMPPConnection.getServiceName());  

                if(data.getRows() != null)
                {
                    Iterator<Row> it = data.getRows();
                    while(it.hasNext())
                    {
                        Row row = it.next();
                        System.out.println(row);
                        Iterator iterator = row.getValues("jid");
                        if(iterator.hasNext())
                        {
                            String value = iterator.next().toString();
                            l.add(value);
                            System.out.println("Iteartor values......"+value);
                        }
                        //Log.i("Iteartor values......"," "+value);
                    }
                    System.out.println("UserName Exists");

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in Loading user search"+e);
            }
            return l;
        }
```

Comment: Downgrader:Please comment before downgrading. Its working solution for me.

Comment: what to put in searchString? I gave my username but it returned this exception

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.DefaultPacketExtension cannot be cast to org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.DataForm

Comment: @MuneebMirza:search string is just a partial username.check with the library you imported

Comment: please tell me the name of library for this specific operation.

Comment: did you used providerManager? edited the answer with imports. check it once