# How to parse ReportedData

Tags: android, eclipse, parsing, xmpp, chat

I'm receiving data in an ReportedData variable. And I have no clue how to get the data out, into a parsable form, pls help.

[The javadoc](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/ReportedData.html) isn't very helpful.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290445/xmpp-iq-result-parsing-issue) is how it all started.

I've tried getCollumns, getRows, to no avail. Or I'm just doing it wrong. Any thoughts?

Here is the code:

```
 ReportedData data = null;
                  UserSearchManager search = new UserSearchManager(ChatList.connection);
                  Form searchForm = null;
                try {
                    searchForm =   search.getSearchForm("search.webserv.xyz.com");
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                  Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();
                    answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);
                    answerForm.setAnswer("search", "android");
                  answerForm.setAnswer("last", "android");
                  try {
                     data = search.getSearchResults(answerForm, "search.webserv.xyz.com"); 
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: What is the ReportedData variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that shows how to parse a ReportedData variable:

```
if(data.getRows() != null)
    {
        Iterator<Row> it = data.getRows();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Row row = it.next();
            Iterator iterator = row.getValues("jid");
            if(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                String value = iterator.next().toString();
                Log.i("Iteartor values......"," "+value);
            }
            //Log.i("Iteartor values......"," "+value);
        }
         Toast.makeText(_service,"Username Exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         );
    }
```